# jquery DataTable - change iDisplayLength dynamically affect paging

Tags: jquery, datatable, paging

I have a jquery DataTable with `"iDisplayLength":-1` (all records), on the first load user will see all records.
This table is refreshing every minute(init the table each refresh - maybe this is not the best?).

```
 function initEventsTable() {

        self.$eventTable = $("#events_table");

        if (self.$eventTable != undefined) {

            self.oTable = self.$eventTable.DataTable({

                "scrollX": true,

                "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],

                // Set the initial value
                "iDisplayLength":-1,

                "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sPrevious": "Prev",
                        "sNext": "Next"
                    }
                },

                aaSorting: [[8, 'desc'], [5, 'asc']],
                bSortable: true,

            });
}
```

The user can change the number of rows (ex. 10 rows ) :

```
$('[name="events_table_length"]').on('change', function () {
        eventsTableLength = $(this).val();
    });
```

After the table refreshed (`initEventsTable()`) i use the code below to change the length:

```
var oSettings = self.oTable.fnSettings();
        if (oSettings != null)
        {
            $('select[name^="events_table_length"] option:selected').attr("selected", null);
            $('select[name^="events_table_length"] option[value=' + eventsTableLength + ']').attr("selected", "selected");
            oSettings._iDisplayLength = eventsTableLength;
            self.oTable.fnDraw();            
        }
```

The problem is with the paging , after refresh when i click on page 2 for example all records appear and not just 10.

Comment: Try start inspect your code for blunders :) `"iDisplayLength":- 1`  breaks the meaning of the property and will show all rows. Why are you trying to set `displayLength` to `- 1`, i.e minus whitespace 1 in the first place? At least `displayLength` should be a positive number.

Comment: Besides that, you would change the displayLength dynamically with `self.oTable.page.len(someValue).draw();`

Comment: self.oTable.page.len(someValue).draw(); is for DataTables 1.10+ , not working for me :-(

Answer (score 0):

I came up  with this:

```
$('select[name^="events_table_length"]').change();
```

Instead focusing on the table , i focus on the dropdown of the length.
I added a `change()`  and that made the magic.